# Execute an INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE against a SQL Server Database Snapshot

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, snapshot

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/10/17/updating-a-database-snapshot.aspx I should be able to successfully execute an INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE against a Database Snapshot.

The idea is to create a view of a table before you create the snapshot, and then  create the snapshot, and update the View in the snapshot.

I have tried this on my SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.2269) and I still get the error 
Failed to update database "Snapshot2015_07" because the database is read-only.

The reason I am keen for this to work is that financials need to be frozen at a particular date, but need to be updated if errors are found in the snapshot.

Has anyone had success recently doing this?
I know there are alternatives like AutoAudit, but it is a lot of work to implement for 1-2 updates/deletes on a database with multiple tables with 5 million + rows

Comment: Snapshots are likely not what you need. A database can have only 1 snapshot at a time and the snapshot is not portable. Because pages are copied to the snapshot before they are updated in the original database, there's a significant performance hit in keeping a database snapshot around. Maybe you should consider a backup or even detaching the .MDF and use that as your frozen-time.

Comment: The view has to specify the database name (which is the original database name, not the snapshot database name), along with the schema and table name.  Does the view you created specify those three parts of the fully qualified object name?

Comment: DMason, that was it! Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

The view has to specify the database name (which is the original database name, not the snapshot database name), along with the schema and table name. Ensure the view you created specifies those three parts of the fully qualified object name.